# Linux directory with space?

Tags: linux

I am attempting to run something for a class.

```
-bash-4.1$ w330=/network_shares/w_drive/c\ s/CJohnson/cs330
-bash-4.1$ cd .. && $w330/freql/test_freql
-bash: /network_shares/w_drive/c: No such file or directory
```

From the looks of it, it doesn't seem to be recognizing any of the directory name after the c even though i did a \ for the space?  What's going on here?  Why is it just stopping after the c?

Comment: try a forward slash instead?

Comment: The folder is "c s" though?  The backslash is supposed to add a space?

Comment: `$w330` is ok ("\ " or "backslash space" correctly embeds space into variable), but $w330 usage is invalid. Use not `$w330/freql/test_freql` but `"$w330/freql/test_freql"`

Comment: @Jack you are right - check your answers.

Comment: Avoid putting spaces in directory names (unless you want to test students for their knowledge about shells).

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead: `w330="/network_shares/w_drive/c s/CJohnson/cs330"`

and this: `"$w330/freql/test_freql"`

Comment: I get the exact same error.

Comment: Jack, when you use w330 and it contains spaces, put the `$w330` into quotes: `"$w330"`